# Sql query to get mutual friends

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I have two tables one is called users ( id,first name,last name...) second one is called followings which contains data about which user is following other users

Followings table example

```
userId   followerId
6           10
6           2
6           3
8           1
8           2
8           3
```

How do I get number of mutual friends between two users

Expected result should be

```
first_user second_user num_of_mutual_friends
    83          73               3
```

Comment: Hi nikola, have you had a look at this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10043135/mysql-query-for-mutual-friends

Comment: @nivlac Yes but his table has some additional rows...that is making me confused

Comment: Sample data is great, but you should also specify the expected result.

Comment: @jarlh I added that also

Comment: Please define "mutual friends".  Does "friendship" have to do with "following"?

Comment: Friends = Followings that is the same logic followers friends etc @GordonLinoff

Comment: Utterly confusing, how do you get that result from the given table data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH firstUser AS (
    SELECT followerId
    FROM followings
    WHERE userId = 6 
)
, secondUser AS (
    SELECT followerId
    FROM followings
    WHERE userId = 8 
)

SELECT COUNT(followerId)
FROM firstUser
INNER JOIN secondUser ON firstUser.followerId = secondUser.followerId
```

Comment: This query is returning error on INNER JOIN part where equal sign is @MTwem

Comment: sorry, forgot the ON clause

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of achieving what you want, but this should do the trick:

```sql
select
  f.userId as first_user,
  s.userId as second_user,
  count(*) as num_of_mutual_friends
from
  followings f
  inner join followings s on s.followerId = f.followerId
                         and s.userId = 6
where
  f.userId = 8
group by
  f.userId,
  s.userId
```

You can check [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f34ac3b2d50db0ea220cbc55e51c6bd1) a working example.

Answer (score 0):

Join from users to both followings:

```
select u.*
from users
join followings a on a.followerId = u.id
  and a.userid = 6
join followings b on b.followerId = u.id
  and b.userid = 8
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this using subqueries. So, if you want to get the number of mutual followers between user with id 8 and user with id 6, you can use this:

**SOLUTION 1:**

`SELECT COUNT(followerId) AS mutual_followers_count FROM followings WHERE userId = 6  AND followerId IN (SELECT followerId FROM followings WHERE userId = 8)`

**SOLUTION 2:**

`SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(followerId)) AS mutual_followers_count FROM followings  WHERE followerId in (SELECT followerId FROM followings WHERE userId = 6)  AND followerId in (SELECT followerId FROM followings WHERE userId = 8)`