# Check Mutual Friends from my friend using MySql

Tags: php, mysql, database, join, left-join

For the first table:

```
user_id | name
1         Me
2         Jeremy
3         Bob
4         Kelvin
```

For the second table:

```
user_id | friend_id
1         2
1         3
2         1
2         3
3         1
3         2
```

Therefore, the friend relationship will like this:

user_id 1 - 2,3

user_id 2 - 1,3

user_id 3 - 1,2

If let say I'm user_id 1 which is 'Me', then I need to display all my friends and show the mutual friends. Similar to facebook 'all friends' feature that will show the mutual friends. 
The input will be '1' the output will be

user_id 2 return 1 mutual friends

user_id 3 return 1 mutual friends

I've been researching a long time, but have not tried out workable code.

Comment: This answer can help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10043135/mysql-query-for-mutual-friends

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use self joins and aggregation:

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.name, 
       COUNT(f3.friend_id) mutual_friends
FROM friends f1
INNER JOIN friends f2 ON f2.user_id = f1.friend_id
INNER JOIN users u ON u.user_id = f2.user_id
LEFT JOIN friends f3 ON f3.user_id = f1.user_id AND f3.friend_id = f2.friend_id
WHERE f1.user_id = ?
GROUP BY u.user_id, u.name;
```

Replace `?` with user id that you want.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=eaffedcd7c384afda3bdc6037de3396c).

Comment: @VoonTaoTan which name?

Comment: The 'name' field from the first table.

Comment: For example:
id = 2 ,name = 'Jeremy' ,2 = mutual friends

Comment: @VoonTaoTan see my edited answer.

Comment: while I use this set of data, ('1', '2'),
  ('1', '3'),
  ('1', '4'),
  ('2', '1'),
  ('2', '3'),
  ('3', '1'),
  ('3', '2'),
  ('4', '1')

if the id input is 1, the mutual friend works fine, but if the input id is 2, the mutual friends seems weird. the mutual friends for id1 and id2 should both are 1 right? but the results different

Comment: @VoonTaoTan check my edited code

Comment: Yes, It works perfectly fine. Thanks for the help. I'll mark this question as solved, thus can help others.